# Covering cars or vans with advertisement images, what is this called?

Tags: phrase-requests

I have been working as a graphic designer for a while and we design and print advertisement material and cover cars / vans with it.

What do we call this in English?

I am preparing my CV and I don't know how to put it there.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [The Food Truck Handbook, 2012](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tDLCf25ZdkgC&pg=PA94&dq=%22vehicle%20wrapping%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=P6A3UeOpFIaHPZ-RgfAN&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22vehicle%20wrapping%22&f=false):

> **Wraps**
>    *Vehicle wrapping* is also known as *vehicle graphics, transit graphics, wrap advertising, transit advertising,* and *vehicle decals.*

I'm a bit surprised they didn't also include the term most familiar to me ([vehicle signage](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22good%20one,%20and%20people%20are%20mad%20for%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22vehicle%20signage%22&oq=%22vehicle%20signage%22&gs_l=serp.3...174305.177781.0.178277.15.15.0.0.0.0.89.878.15.15.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.-Fi5LB6ZArs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1319&bih=897)). Perhaps that's because I'm UK-based, I don't know.

Another term frequently used in this context is [Custom Livery](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Custom%20Livery%20pictures&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=of43UZD_LIfYPYnxgJAN&ved=0CDAQsAQ&biw=1319&bih=897). There's a preponderance of racing cars in the images in that link, but I associate the expression more with buses/coaches, shop delivery vans, and haulage lorries. To me, *livery* is either pure decoration, or it normally advertises the *owners of the vehicle*. So I don't really like seeing it applied to racing cars which are mainly covered with *advertisements for sponsors*. I suppose you could say the sponsors "own" the car, but it doesn't seem quite right to me if all they did was supply the oil, for example.

Comment: 'Vehicle signage' would be understood by non-experts (in contrast to 'wrapping'

Answer (score 13):

It's called [wrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrap_advertising).

<sub>Not much more to say, really. This really is a three-word answer.</sub>

Comment: I've used it as vehicle wrapping. I was thinking covering. I'm still not sure. Wanted to know if there is a special term for this... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it specifically referred to as "vinyl wrapping" when using vinyl for the wrap.  I have no idea if other materials are ever used as I've only ever heard of vinyl wrapping.